# Rollup - ignore some imports

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, ecmascript-6, rollup

I am using Vuetify `1.5.18` and have the following code...

```js
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
...
// rollup config
import VuePlugin from 'rollup-plugin-vue';
import css from 'rollup-plugin-css-only';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import pkg from './package.json';

// const external = Object.keys(pkg.dependencies);
const plugins = [
    resolve({
      module: true,
      main: true
    }),
    commonjs(),
    VuePlugin(),
    css()
];
module.exports = {
  plugins,
  input: 'src/index.js',
  output: {
    file: 'dist/index.js',
    format: 'esm'
  }
};
```

But when I run *rollup* I get the following in my output...

```
import vue from 'vue';
```

And when I try to run I get the following error...

> Failed to resolve module specifier "vue". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

I load Vue not in the UI project but in my server like this...

```
// Footer.pug
script(type="module")
          | import Vue from '/vue/vue.esm.browser.js'
          | const global = window || global;
          | global.Vue = Vue;
```

So that line shouldn't be there. If I remove Vuetify it goes away. Also if I point to the version I have hosted through the Koa app like this...

```
import * as Vuetify from '/vuetify/vuetify.js';
```

Everything seems to work as well. I can also go in and manually remove the `import Vuetify from 'vuetify'` and add this line to the template on the server...

```
| const global = window || global;
| global.vue = global.Vue;
```

Is there a way I can tell rollup to ignore any "vue" imports?

Comment: Unfortunate that no one has even commented for all this time. The plugin `rollup-plugin-ignore` ignoring the package in question fixed the issue for me

Comment: Bit late, but I think you were looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/a/71552903/812919