# Vite - How do I use a wildcard in Rollupjs build.rollupOptions.external?

Tags: rollupjs, vite

I'm using Vite to build a library and I get the following error when building the library:

```
Rollup failed to resolve import "node:path"
```

By adding the failed import to the Rollup options I'm able to fix the error but the build continues to complain for each `node:*` import. In the end I've had to add each one individually to the `build.rollupOptions.external`:

```js
build: {
  rollupOptions: {
    external: [            
      'node:path',           
      'node:https',
      'node:http',
      'node:zlib',
      ... 
    ],
},
```

While this solves the issue it is time consuming to list each `node` import individually. Is there instead a way to use some sort of wildcard syntax to automatically resolve all `node` imports?

```js
build: {
  rollupOptions: {
    external: [             
      'node:*' // i.e. this syntax does not work, is there something similar that would work?
    ],
},
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[`build.rollupOptions.external`](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#external) also accepts [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). The following [`RegExp`](https://regex101.com/r/Sf1bI9/1) matches any string that starts with `node:`:

```js
/^node:.*/
```

So configure `external` as follows:

```js
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      external: [
        /^node:.*/,
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Did now know, should have checked the docs again, thanks XD

Comment: I found this answer while looking for a method to filter out all external dependencies. To filter all of them out, put `/node_modules/` into the array.